# How can 'clmul' intrinsics be used to improve computation of CRC in RISCV?

Tags: c, math, crc

My goal is to understand and improve the computation of CRC using `clmul` instructions in RISCV.
The way described in RISCV bitmanip documentation is following:

4.8 Cyclic redundency checks (CRC)

There are special instructions for performing CRCs using the two most widespread 32-bit CRC
polynomials, CRC-32 and CRC-32C.
CRCs with other polynomials can be computed efficiently using CLMUL. The following examples
RISC-V Bitmanip Extension V0.93 83
are using CRC32Q.
The easiest way of implementing CRC32Q with clmul is using a Barrett reduction. On RV32:

```c
uint32_t crc32q_simple(const uint32_t *data, int length) {
    uint32_t P = 0x814141AB;    // CRC polynomial (implicit x^32)
    uint32_t mu = 0xFEFF7F62;   // x^64 divided by CRC polynomial
    uint32_t mu1 = 0xFF7FBFB1;  // "mu" with leading 1, shifted right by 1 bit
    uint32_t crc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        crc ^= rev8(data[i]);
        crc = clmulr(crc, mu1);
        crc = clmul(crc, P);
    }
    return crc;
}
```

I already know how constants `mu` and `mu1` are computed, but I still have questions:

- Why can original internal loop be replaced with `clmul` intrinsics? This is not stated in documentation. For reference, this is a generic CRC code sample for `CRC-32/AIXM`:

```c
uint32_t crc32_bitwise_aixm(const uint8_t* data, size_t length) {   
  uint32_t crc = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    uint8_t byte = data[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if ((crc ^ (byte << 24)) & 0x80000000)
        crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x814141ab; // Here is the polynomial from which constants mu and mu1 are computed
      else
        crc = crc << 1;
      byte = byte << 1;
    }
  }
  return crc;
}
```

- I know how this constants are computed, but the question is, WHY are they computed and why passing them to `clmul` makes working CRC?
- What is `0x80000000` constant in original CRC loop? I think it has something to do with masking portion of number `byte << 24`.

Comment: Is the resulting CRC returned the same for both functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is too much to explain in an answer here. Since you don't even understand the `0x80000000`, you need to first understand at least the basic mathematics of cyclic redundancy check and importantly their practical implementations. I recommend [Ross William's guide](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt). The simple answer for just your specific question is that it is implementing a linear feedback shift register that shifts up, and is reading the top bit to feed back into the other bits using an exclusive-or mask. However you also need to understand how it is that such a shift register implements a polynomial division over GF(2), where a CRC is the remainder of such a division.

Once you understand all that, then you're ready for how to do a CRC using multiplication instead of division. You already named the approach, called [Barrett's Reduction](https://www.corsix.org/content/barrett-reduction-polynomials), originally for integer division but applied here to polynomial division. Read that post. In gross terms, you are replacing division by a polynomial with multiplication by the reciprocal of that polynomial. Your `mu` is the reciprocal. Carry-less multiplication is polynomial multiplication, where each bit in a register is the coefficient of a polynomial over GF(2).

Comment: Thank you! I think the proper guide is what I needed. I thought I knew basic CRC math, since the algorithm is obvious, but it seems like there is a lot happenning behind the stage.

Comment: Looking at your link for Barrett Reduction, it is calculating a quotient, S / P, but CRC is a modulo function, S % P. The normal CRC sequence, ignoring shifts, using the OP's variables would be quotient = CRC * mu1, product = quotient * P, CRC ^= product. Does the rev8, clmulr, clmul sequence do the equivalent? Link to Intel's [carryless multiply example for the Barrett Reduction step](https://www.intel.cn/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/fast-crc-computation-generic-polynomials-pclmulqdq-paper.pdf#page=14) .